# IIS Rewrite rule for mobile devices - Causing loop

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

In my IIS application there is an internal url, that i would like to redirect the client if the user is browsing via mobile.

I tried the following URL rewrite rule, which do redirect part but also causing Too Many redirect loop.

```
  <rule name="Mobile Rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
          <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino" />
          <add input="{URL}" pattern=".*MMEducation/ScreenEdRegistration" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="MMEducation/ScreenEdRegistration" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
```

Anyone can suggest me how to solve this problem with rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

The `{URL}` in conditions is same as `url` in action.

For example, mobile devices send a request `http://example.com/MMEducation/ScreenEdRegistration`. It match the condition of {URL}, IIS will redirect it to `http://example.com/MMEducation/ScreenEdRegistration`. URL never change after redirecting. The redirected URL still match  the condition and  IIS will redirect is again..... Loop and loop again and loop again again...

So you need to make sure the redirected url won't match the condition so that the issue can be solved.

By the way, you can refer to [this](https://forums.iis.net/t/1169853.aspx?URL%20rewrite%20for%20Mobile%20Cell%20phone%20devices) about how to redirect url for mobile devices.